# Encriptar password 50 caracteres en VARBINARY(8000)

Tags: c#, sql

Si encripto una contraseña de 50 caracteres en un campo `VARBINARY(8000)`, ¿ocupa algún espacio extra al ser longitud 8000? ¿o es cómo el `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 3):

Actúa como un `VARCHAR`, si la longitud de tu campo va a estar variando es recomendable que utilices `VARBINARY` de lo contrario usarías `BINARY`

Fuente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score 3):

El tipo de dato `VARBINARY(N)` o `VARBINARY(8000)` es equivalente a 8 Kilobytes, así que no te ocuparía espacio extra, el `VARBINARY(MAX)` que retiene información de hasta 2,000,000,000 bytes que es el equivalente a 2 GB.

Así que por defecto el espacio utilizado es de 8 kilobytes.